# Keep getting "JavaScript heap out of memory" during while loop for web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, cheerio

Getting the error "*FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory*."
The Nodejs file keeps running out of memory. Tried the same code with a for loop with five as the end, worked very well. Somehow, I keep getting the err msg when I use While Loop or do_while loop.

Help me identify the cause of the error, why the loop is not breaking. I have already increased the memory allocation to 2048.

```
    var express = require("express");
    const request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    var list = [];
    var hasNext = true;
    var index = 1;
    do{
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://www.thedsu.ca/club-and-collective-types/club/page/' + index + '/?post_type=club_and_collective'
        }, (err, res, body) => {
            
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            let $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('div[class="block-grid-2 block-grid-flatten tax-club-collective-grid"]').find('div > div > a').each(function(index, element) {
                list.push($(element).attr('href'));
            });
            index++
            console.dir(list);
            if($('body').attr('class') == 'error404'){
                console.log('empty');
                hasNext = false;
            }
        });
    }while(hasNext);
```

Comment: Your `request()` function is **asynchronous**.  The loop termination flag will not be set until at least one request returns.

Comment: You are running ALL your requests in parallel. thus they all take up memory at the same time (max memory consumption).  If you want to lower the memory consumption, you would run only N requests at a time, where N is something like 1 to 5.  Running 1 at a time would be serializing them.

Comment: And, because Node.js is single-threaded with a queue of events, the callbacks will *never* be called. After getting an understanding of asynchronicity, yes, you should switch to a library like [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) and use async/await.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code runs out of memory is that it starts a very large number of *asynchronous* calls at the same time. The reason for this is that the call to `request` is not blocking the execution, and the loop does not wait for the callback to run before invoking the next `request`.

Changing your code to use async/await (or promises) instead of callbacks would probably be the cleanest solution.

Using callbacks, you can do something like:

```
< require calls here >
< initial configurations here>

function runRequestForIndex(idx) {
    request({<parameters>},
      (err, res, body) => {
          < your logic here >

          if($('body').attr('class') == 'error404'){
              console.log('empty');
          } else {
              runRequestForIndex(idx+1) // The next iteration 
          }
    });
}

runRequestForIndex(index)
```

Comment: I started learning the python module (they are much better to maintain as a beginner), thanks for the help!